# What can I do if I'm stuck RDP to my Azure VM?

Tags: azure, azure-vm-role

We set up a VM on Azure used just like a normal VM therefore lots of data our on the VM, however this morning the VM suddenly stopped working - I guess there's something wrong inside (possible harddisk full or windows service issue)

How can I fix this please...

Comment: This appears to be related to something Azure-specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We had the same issue today, beware that currently there are issues with Azure Storage in North and West Europe.

In our case the problem is with the attached disks on the VM's which are using the Azure Storage.

You can check the Azure Status here: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/status/

Comment: yeah stefdev - got it confirmed from Microsoft... what a nightmare!!